# How to Insert image on web page using image name pulled from access database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007

I'm developing a website.  I have an Access database that I pull image names from that i want to use as parameters to post images from my folder using C# code in VS 2010.  I want to know how to access the image name as a string and insert it into my asp image element. I'm guessing I need to store the results of my "Select" query in a variable in order to pass it through the "Eval" function, but I'm just guessing and nor have I figured out how to do it.

The following section of code is where I established a connection with the database, used the Datalist control to list the information on my webpage that this code is for. And so what I'm trying to ultimately do is use the file name that's in the database as a parameter to grab the correct image from my files and post it to my web page.  See below in code where I say ***FILENAME GOES HERE?????*** to see where I need to put my filename for my picture.

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
     DataFile="~/App_Data/TravelJoansDB.accdb" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table2]"></asp:AccessDataSource>
     <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" 
             ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID">
         <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
         <ItemTemplate> 
                ID:
                <asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                <br />
                Image:
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" Eval(*FILENAME GOES HERE?????*) %>' />
                <br />
                <br />
         </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" + Eval("Your_ImageName_Column")%>' />
```